# PhpMyAdmin depends on php7.0 instead of 7.1

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, dependencies

I have php7.1 installed on my Ubuntu Linux. I've just installed PhpMyAdmin 4.6.6 as well. It seems that PhpMyAdmin requires php7.0 and automatically downloads and installs it. Now I have two versions of PHP with the older 7.0 being used by default. When I try uninstalling php7.0, PhpMyAdmin gets uninstalled automatically.

On PhpMyAdmin website it is stated that PhpMyAdmin 4.6.6 is compatible with php7.1. So why am I experiencing this problem, and what would be the best way to overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was too fast to post a question. I've solved the problem myself. It seems that my php7.1 has not been properly installed. I've reinstalled php7.1 and after that I was able to remove php7.0 without losing any other packages or functionalities.